# Why is a variable of a predefined type included under "generic"? (Ada)

Tags: generics, ada

I'm currently in college for CS, and I just started my data structures and algorithms class. My professor strongly prefers (practically forces us) that we use Ada. In order to get ahead, I started to looking up some things and found this snippet of code describing how a generic stack might be written:

```
generic
  Max: Positive; 
  type Element_T is private;
package Generic_Stack is
  procedure Push (E: Element_T);
  function Pop return Element_T;
end Generic_Stack;
```

What stuck out to me was the variable "Max." Since it is of type positive, it didn't seem logical that it would be generic. Perhaps I'm still too new to the idea, but I thought the idea behind a generic was that it is basically an empty shell and can be interchanged with different data types upon instantiating.

Maybe I just don't understand generics well enough. If not, could somebody please enlighten me?

Comment: See also [*Generic programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming).

Comment: Also, See Also [Ada Generic Programming](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Generics)

Comment: I've read up on both articles, but it still doesn't quite answer my question. In the Ada Generic Programming article, I think I found a section pertaining to what I am getting at, but I'm still not sure what it's trying to say exactly. What seems intuitive to be is to simply declare and define Max inside the package.

Comment: The generic quality of `Max` is that it allows the size of a stack to be generic, to become an actual size only when `Generic_Stack` is instantiated (a compile time arrangement). Some size information such as `Max` is then needed if, e.g., `Max` is used in the body of the package for an array of `1..Max` elements.

Answer (score 3):

Having a variable in the formal part of the generic is a way to pass a constant (at compile time) to configure your generic. Such a constant can be used to define other variables in some data structures (like an array (1..Max)), which cannot always be achieved by passing a value as a parameter to a subprogram.
Also, this ensures that both Push and Pop are used with the same "Max" constant (that would not make sense to pass such a constant as a parameter to both subprograms)

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow. Why would it not make sense to pass it as a paramter? Also, I still don't understand why it has to be under generic. If I had not been aware of this snippet of code, I probably would have just defined it inside the package.

Comment: You can define it inside the package with the same result. But then people who want to use your package have no control over it. An example would be that you decide that an array size should be 20, but if a user wanted a size of 30 he would have to duplicate the source to change the constant. Whereas if you pass it in the formal part, users get control of it, and can simply instantiate your package multiple times with different values for the constant.

Comment: I see. But what if I added a procedure in the package that allowed the user to change the value, even if it's defined inside the package?

Comment: Then it is no longer a constant. I you cannot use it to define a type such a `type My_Array is array (1 .. Max) of Integer`

Comment: But if I put it in the formal part, I could let the user manipulate max?

Comment: That probably wouldn't be re-entrant or thread-safe. But going back to the essence of your question, I'd say that that particular use of a parameter caters to a different necessity than a generic type. In most occasions, the same effect could be achieved with a type discriminant or by using dynamic allocations. But, when programming fixed-size stack-based data structures, you could be in a bind without this ability. I can't think right now of a convincing small example, but this is one of the features I've missed many times in c++/java templates once used to it.

Comment: Perhaps a simple example might be defining public ranged subtypes. I can't think of another way if they have to be at the library level (i.e., "globals").

Comment: Another example is to pass a `Checks:Boolean` formal parameter. Your code can then have one or more `if Checks then expansive_checks`. This code will never be compiled by the compiler if the variable is set to `False` in the instantiation of the generic.